# Homomorphism of Groups (Introduction the Representation Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

**Definition(Representation).** A representation of a group $G$ is a homomorphism $\phi : G \to GL(V)$ for some (finite-dimensional) vector space V.

Example:
$\phi : \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbb{C}^{*}$ defined by $\phi([m])= e^{\frac{2\pi im}{n}}$ is a representation. 
Well, $\phi([m] + [p]) = \phi([m+p]) := e^{\frac{2\pi i(m+p)}{n}} = e^{\frac{2\pi im+ 2\pi ip)}{n}} = e^{\frac{2\pi im}{n}}*e^{\frac{2\pi ip}{n}} = \phi([m])*\phi([p]).$

Just show this to $\phi$ be a representation? This is prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism? Is it normal to apply $\phi$ to a sum for example and get a mutiplication?

Comment: The cyclic group with $n$ elements can be written in additive notation with identity $0$ and generator $1$ so that $\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_n = n .1 = 0$. Or in multiplicative notation with identity $1$ and generator $g$ so that $\underbrace{g \cdot \ \ldots\ \cdot g}_n = g^n = 1$. Letting $g = e^{2i \pi /n}$ gives the homomorphism (isomorphism) you stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism between the groups $(G,+)$ and $(H,\cdot)$, we must show, for all $f,g \in G$,
$$  \varphi(f + g) = \varphi(f) \cdot \varphi(g)  \text{.}  $$

That is, the image of the $G$-operation on two elements of $g$ is the $H$-operation on the images of the two elements.

What you have quoted shows that your $\phi$ truly is a homomorphism.

What one shows is that $\phi$ applied to "the operation in the first object" turns into "the operation in the second object" applied to the correct arguments.  In your example, the operation in the first object is "$+$" and the operation in the second object is matrix multiplication.